# How to move the div with delay on each step

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which I need to move to right side. If the input is lets say steps = 1000, then div needs to move at right side with the increment of 50. I need to make this movement look like a step of 50 then few second stop they from 50 to 100.

```
<button>Start</button>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function(){
        var steps = 1000;
        for(var i =0; i<=steps; i+50)
        {
            $("div").animate({left: i+'px'});
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: have you looked at using setTimeout or SetInterval?

Comment: @ADyson, i did tried setInterval and delay

Comment: what was the problem with using those, then? They should provide you with the delay of a few seconds that you're looking for. If it didn't quite work for you, maybe show what you did. You certainly need to use one or other of them to do what you want.

Comment: or [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in JS:

```
setInterval(function() {
  elem.style.left = ( left += 10 ) + "px";
}, 100);
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb96ys5h/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `for` loop to this , to have a step by 50:

```
 for(var i =0;i<=steps;i+=50){ 
    $("div").animate({left: i+'px'});
 }
```